# converting maven project into dynamic web project

Tags: java, maven

I want to change my `maven project` into `dynamic web project`.  I deleted `pom.xml` file and I created  a new work space and I imported the project. I'm getting following errors. I added all jar files required.

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.
Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.
```

Comment: You say you added all jars required. Did you add the jar containing `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create fresh project in Ecplise. Create package directories or copy whole source code directory from HDD to "src" folder in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

1. Go to your project in project explorer window.
2. Right click and select Maven from list.
3. Select "Disable Maven Nature"

After that clean the project once and build the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

**Right click on your project**

Visit
 - properties
 - project facet
 - on right select Dynamic web module

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

add **commons-logging-x.x.x.jar** to your classpath. Simple!!

The error itself is telling what to do.